# Assign JTextField's text to the next element of an array

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to assign the number value from the `JTextField` to the next index in the array and then increment the index variable but I'm not sure on the code.

```
inputField = new JTextField( 10 );

private int num;
private int index = 0;
private int array[] = new int[ 10 ];
private String result;

try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
    array[index] = num;
    index++;
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is not so much *how* to do it, because you already show us that you know how to increment an int and get a number from a JTextField, but rather **when** to do it. Usually this needs to be done at the instigation of an event such as the push of a JButton or by pressing enter in a JTextField, both of which can trigger an ActionListener -- and so there's your solution -- add an ActionListener to both your JTextField **and** a JButton, and in the listener, get your text, parse it, increment your array index, and add the number to the array.

Comment: I have added the ActionListener and it seems to be working. Just to clarify the code I have above will pass num to the array right?

Comment: @macattack: the code you've posted above will not compile, so there's no way for me to tell you if it will work. Your best bet is to try it, test it, and see.

Comment: All good. I fixed it up but I was getting an outOfBoundsException. Not to worry though, I figured it out. Thanks!